# Xcopy a whole folder [with all in it] ...BUT, how do I make Xcopy create a different folder every time or ask to create a new or overwrite?

Tags: xcopy

I explain.

I have this short .bat file to copy a 'folder' with all contents and it does create the folder named Source_folder with all contents.

When I re-run it, Xcopy obviously find that folder named 'Source_folder' and does copy/overwrite all contents - which is fine.

Here is the simple bat file:

```
ECHO OFF
Xcopy "c:/SOURCE/folder" "c:/DESTINATION" /Y /O /X /E /H /K
PAUSE
```

What can I do to have the folder 'Source_folder' re-created as Source_folder01, then next time Source_folder02 and so on?

Just to have a series of copies at various dates.

So in the DESTINATION [folder] I find:
Source_folder
Source_folder01
Source_folder02
Source_folder03
etc.

Thank you in advance for your time.

M

Comment: Use common IF EXISTS and SET /A...

Comment: How do I do that?
I am not a developer, just an advanced Computer user ...

Thanks

Comment: @AstroStak Read the documentation. [If - Conditionally perform command - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html).

Comment: A better solution is to use a version control system ...